# How to add a string to a String Array

Tags: android, arrays

I'm new to Android studio and I have this kind of problem. I want to add a text to `fragB` from `fragA` using checkboxes from `fragA`. When I select one CheckBox, the text will appear but when I select the other CheckBox, the text that should be added is not visible. It will only be visible when I unchecked the other CheckBox.

Please help me.

here's my fragA:

```
public class fragA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    CheckBox c1,c2,c3;
    communicator comm;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_a,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm=(communicator)getActivity();
        c1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.c1);
        c1.setOnClickListener(this);
        c2=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.c2);
        c2.setOnClickListener(this);
        c3=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.c3);
        c3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String final_text=" ";
        ArrayList<String> selection=new ArrayList<String>();
        if(c1.isChecked()){
            selection.add("O");
            for(String Selections:selection){
                final_text=final_text+Selections+"\n";
            }
        }
        else if(c2.isChecked()) {
            selection.add("My");
            for(String Selections:selection){
                final_text=final_text+Selections+"\n";
            }
        }
        else if(c3.isChecked()) {
            selection.add("God");
            for(String Selections:selection){
                final_text=final_text+Selections+"\n";
            }
        }
            comm.respond(""+final_text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because more than one check box can be checked. If you want only want one thing to be selected at any given time use RadioButtons or unselect the other check boxes when a new one is selected.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. But i want to select multiple checkboxes at a time and i cant . for example i selected the c1 and c2 so the output will be "O My" but it didn't.  It just shows "O" because i selected c1 first

Comment: remove "else if" then. Just have each check in their own "if' statement, no 'else if'  because It will only check one and not the others when it reads true. So: if (c1.isChecked()) {//whatever}, if (c2.isChecked()) {//whatever} and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i solved my own question. Instead of using if eslse statements, i used case.
now when i checked the all of the checkbox, all text will be visible and when i uncheck one, the text of that checkbox will be deleted.
i used the following codes for `fragA`:

```
public class fragA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    CheckBox c1,c2,c3;
    communicator comm;
    ArrayList<String> selection=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_a,container,false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm=(communicator)getActivity();
        c1=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.c1);
        c1.setOnClickListener(this);
        c2=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.c2);
        c2.setOnClickListener(this);
        c3=(CheckBox)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.c3);
        c3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
        String final_work="";
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.c1:
                if(checked) {
                    selection.add("O");
                    for (String Selections : selection) {
                        final_work = final_work + Selections + "\n";
                    }comm.respond(""+final_work);
                }

                else
                    {
                        selection.remove("O");
                        for (String Selections : selection) {
                            final_work = final_work + Selections + "\n";
                        }comm.respond(""+final_work);
                    }
                break;
            case R.id.c2:
                if(checked)
                {selection.add("My");
                    for (String Selections : selection) {
                            final_work = final_work + Selections + "\n";
                        }comm.respond(""+final_work);
                    }
                else
                {selection.remove("My");
                    for (String Selections : selection) {
                            final_work = final_work + Selections + "\n";
                        }comm.respond(""+final_work);
                    }
                break;
            case R.id.c3:
                if(checked)
                {selection.add("God");
                    for (String Selections : selection) {
                            final_work = final_work + Selections + "\n";
                        }comm.respond(""+final_work);
                    }
                else
                {selection.remove("God");
                    for (String Selections : selection) {
                            final_work = final_work + Selections + "\n";
                        }comm.respond(""+final_work);}
                break;
        }
    }
}
```